# What are ways to make enemies count as bloodied?

Tags: dnd-4e

How can I make an enemy count as bloodied in 4e? I'm having an awesome idea for a character that substitutes intimidate for diplomacy, and I was looking for a way to make opponents be considered bloodied (making them viable targets for intimidation/diplomacy checks to force them to surrender)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, good first question.  Please take a look at the [About] (it's like a tour).

Comment: The 1st thing that pops into my mind is a Flensing Weapon, it has a daily that when you hit with an attack you can give the target an untyped 5 ongoing damage and is considered bloodied (save ends both).

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

The first is the Tiefling Psionic Paragon Path [Infernal Eye](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=571). The Augment 2 encounter power for this PP is:

> Effect: Until the end of your next turn, the target is considered bloodied for all effects. (Player's Handbook Races p24)

The other is the [Flensing Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1317) which has a Daily power that reads (credit to [Tijnkwan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/9912/tijnkwan) on this one):

> Use this power when you hit with the weapon. The target takes ongoing 5 damage and is considered bloodied even if it has more hit points than its bloodied value (save ends). (Dragon 368, p65)

Both of these would allow for intimidate checks to force enemies to flee.

Comment: +1 for using my comment and crediting me (It's Tijnkwan btw :P). I didnt think would be worth a full answer so that is why I only commented.

Comment: @Tijnkwan thanks, I thought I'd axed that first n, but I've fixed it now.

Comment: The flensing link is useless as it points to a login page.

Comment: @bmargulies both of the links go to wizards' compendium database which *is* behind a paywall. I can snag the book and page refs from there and post them though.